# How to delete a specific device?

Tags: google-fabric

I've been using Crashlytics/Fabric for quite a long time now and there is devices that are long dead (and also for my tester).

Each time I try to upload a new version I have a message saying : "hey you forgot to take these 1950 era devices". So I want to remove these devices... and I can't find the option in the setting.

Do you have any ideas?

(I'm working on macOS)

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. To remove tester's devices, you need to reach out to support(at)fabric(dot)io with the bundle id of the app, email address of the tester and device UUID that you want removed.

Comment: There is a way to remove the devices if you reach out to our wonderful support folks. I understand your desire to have this functionality yourself. Please remember that Stack Overflow has a "Be Nice" policy: https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Comment: This is quite inconvenient. In my case, one of the testers changed their iPhone. I just want to remove the old iPhone from the list.